# Merging the values of a Collection in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I've been giving this problem some thought. What I've tried so far is reading, searching and trying the Collections' documentation with no luck on what I'm trying to do.

What I'm trying to achieve is to merge all products by "product_id", sum the "qty", and get an array of "responsibles" for the same product into one new collection:

I have the following information from my database:

```
[
   {
      "qty":"8",
      "product_id":6,
      "product":{
         "id":6,
         "name":"Mantequilla",
         "barcode":"123456789",
         "full_name":"Mantequilla - 123456789"
      },
      "itbis":"0",
      "precio":"0",
      "responsible":"Juan"
   },
   {
      "qty":"4",
      "product_id":6,
      "product":{
         "id":6,
         "name":"Mantequilla",
         "barcode":"123456789",
         "full_name":"Mantequilla - 123456789"
      },
      "itbis":"0",
      "precio":"0",
      "responsible":"Carlos"
   },
   {
      "qty":"3",
      "product_id":8,
      "product":{
         "id":8,
         "name":"Papas",
         "barcode":"4567894456",
         "full_name":"Papas - 4567894456"
      },
      "itbis":"0",
      "precio":"0",
      "responsible":"Pedro"
   }
]
```

***Would then be converted to this:***

```
[
   {
      "qty":"12",
      "product_id":6,
      "product":{
         "id":6,
         "name":"Mantequilla",
         "barcode":"123456789",
         "full_name":"Mantequilla - 123456789"
      },
      "itbis":"0",
      "precio":"0",
      "responsible": ["Juan", "Carlos"]
   }
   {
      "qty":"3",
      "product_id":8,
      "product":{
         "id":8,
         "name":"Papas",
         "barcode":"4567894456",
         "full_name":"Papas - 4567894456"
      },
      "itbis":"0",
      "precio":"0",
      "responsible":"Pedro"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $arr = [...]; // Your input array

        $res = collect($arr)
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->map(function ($sub_collection) {
                $first = $sub_collection->first();

                $first['qty']         = array_sum(array_column($sub_collection->toArray(), 'qty'));
                $first['responsible'] = array_merge(array_column($sub_collection->toArray(), 'responsible'));

                return $first;
            })
            ->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. I was not getting my head around how map worked, so i learned how it works and solved my problem.